# How to identify old microcontrollers?

Tags: microcontroller

I have several old microcontrollers, I am sure I bought them over 10 years ago.  It is my assumption that the numbers on these would still be categorized, but I cannot find a way to search the internet by the number to find out what I can use these microcontrollers are for.  When I do a search for the number I generally either find a data sheet about a similar number or nothing at all.  I have 14 so I won't list all the numbers here, but here are a few examples.

- GAL16V8D 15LP C914D16
- 74LS 138 661
- T74LS74B1 98640A

Is there a site that I can enter these numbers in to find out what the purpose of these microcontrollers can do?

Comment: I have to report that I've had no trouble finding datasheets on the web for `GAL16V8` `74LS138` `74LS74`.  By the way, neither of these is a microcontroller.  They are all logic.  GAL is programmable logic.

Comment: Google is your friend...

Comment: @Nick - You, like me, have had years of practice knowing where to chop the strings and find familiar numbers. Given those numbers, the  questioner will have no problem either

Comment: It sounds like you dropped off the numbers not at the spaces but elsewhere.  I.E.  `GAL16V8` I found as well, I assumed it was a different model than `GAL16V8D`.  Is that not the case?

Comment: Suffix letters on IC part numbers often indicate the package or temperature grades.  Letter prefixes usually indicate the manufacturer or original manufacturer (often in non-obvious ways).  However, the "GAL" prefix indicates the general type of the device.  "74LS" is a clear indication that the part is a TTL logic device. (But all such knowledge only comes with experience...)

Comment: (A low-power Schottky TTL logic device, but that's just being picky.)

Comment: Thank you all for clarifying what I really have.  I bought these with a class while studying for Software Engineering years ago.  I remember programming some of them (just placing them in a device with a lever to lock it in place) to pass in the code.  I was under the assumption I only had one logic chip, EE was not my focus at the time, but I still find it very interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of these are microcontrollers, they're all logic (programmable logic in the case of the GAL, fixed in the other two).  Goto sites like Digikey & Mouser to enter full or partial part numbers - if there's ambiguity that a partial part number happens to match two entirely different types of components, it should be pretty clear which it is (usually).

For more generic googling, try just the first several alphanumeric characters of the part number (e.g. GAL16V8, 74LS138, 74LS74), the later characters are not usually helpful to a "just curious" search, and sometimes you need to remove the first one or two characters, but knowing when to do that is an 'acquired skill' :)